# How to pass interface to constructor when creating an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two Activities: the *MainActivity* starts the *NewReminderActivity*. The first one will be notified when a new reminder has been created. Therefore it implements the interface **OnEventAddedListener**.

Do I need to use serialization to add the *MainActivity* to the intent or is there a better solution? I've never seen any examples using serialization to accomplish this and I'm sure it's very common to pass an interface from one activity to another in order to communicate.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnEventAddedListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_addReminder)
        {
             // NewReminderActivity c = new NewReminderActivity(this);
             // Intent intent = new Intent(this, c.getClass()); // this won't work

             Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewReminderActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             return true;
        } else {
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely should not try to pass one activity to another, whether it's by serializing it (which won't even work for a number of reasons) or setting a reference.

Android will take care of cleaning up old activities out of memory, but won't be able to do so as long as you're holding on to a reference from it. *Never hold on to other activities or fragments outside of their context!*

You should follow the documentation on [starting activities and getting results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) by using `startActivityForResult()` and provide that activity's result through `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Just for clarification: Am I only supposed to use callbacks for Activity <-> Fragment communication?

Comment: Not necessarily, there are other options available to you. From a fragment, you can obtain the activity (if it's attached to one) using `getActivity()`. If you know the type, you can cast it to your expected type and call methods on it. Vice-versa, you should be extremely careful; typically you'd query the FragmentManager when trying to locate a specific fragment. Whatever you do, don't in any of those cases hold on to the references, because you'll inhibit the GC from cleaning up those objects.

Comment: I'm just looking for some good code practices. According to this:  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) I should be using callbacks for communication. Any suggestions when to use what (activity<->activity, activity<->fragment)?

Comment: Between activities, through an Intent. When creating a fragment, provide a Bundle. To existing fragments attached to an activity, as that article recommends.